# How to make custom buttons using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make custom buttons using bootstrap. The Get Quote button must have a magnifying glass symbol on it's left and similarly the clear button must have a symbol to it's left as shown in the following image. Also, how to change the color of the Get Quote button to change it to sky blue color.

The image with Get Quote and Clear buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 4, they [dropped the Glyphicon icons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components). You can use:

- the upstream version of [Glyphicons](https://glyphicons.com/)
- [Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/)
- [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)

Coming back to your requirement, you can checkout http://fontawesome.io/examples/ in which examples are given to integrate Font Awesome icons with Bootstrap 3 buttons. Similarly, it can be done with Bootstrap 4 buttons. Check the code snippet provided.

Also, to change the color of the buttons to custom colors apart from the [available options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/), you would obviously have to change the CSS for it. A better way is to go through the SASS files in the source and use the mixins to generate new custom buttons. Checkout the links below to get some idea:

- https://bootbites.com/articles/bootstrap-4-button-customisation/
- https://coursetro.com/posts/design/73/How-to-Customize-Bootstrap-4-with-Sass

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
 <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Get Quote
</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">
 <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Clear
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this website, Useful to both fresher and experienced person. Nice tutorials.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp
```